# Vibration after the car has run for a while

Tags: bmw, vibration, drivetrain, drive-shaft

First question here; go easy on me.

So I have an e30 BMW(1989), the car runs fine however when I have driven for a few minutes a vibration occurs when I travel around 60(kph)

This does not happen when I just start driving, only when the car reaches running temps and has been used a little.

I have just recently replaced the engine mounts and a few months back I have changed the gearbox mounts as well.

I know that the propshaft needs balancing but I'm not sure if this is the cause.

The vibration feels like its coming from the back of my seat. I can't feel it in the pedals which leads me to think that its got something to do with the gearbox or drivetrain

Many thanks to anyone who is able to help here.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site.  If your prop shaft needs balancing, have this done before driving the car any distance.  The vibration you are feeling will be coming from either the differential or the gearbox, the reason it doesn't happen straight away is that the oil in both of these parts is cold to start with and is thicker when cold.

If left unchecked, you stand a good chance of ruining the bearings in your diff which will only add to the expense.  That noise from under your seat is the unbalanced prop shaft vibrating the internals of the rest of your drive-train and the end state is mechanical failure.

Comment: I'm wondering if this version of BMW has a guibo in the driveshaft which needs to be replaced. This wouldn't cause the vibrate only after warming up, but would be consistent with the driveshaft needing to be balanced. I'm also wondering if the reason the OP doesn't get the vibration until after warm up is they aren't moving the vehicle fast enough from the start to reach the point of vibration.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - It actually does - I replaced the guibo and coupling when I replaced the gearbox mounts

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'll go get it balanced right away and get back to you :)

Comment: @GiannisKatsini - Yes, "gui**b**o" ... I was thinking of someone named Sarduchi or something, lol. :o)